# Why is "Use MFC in a Static Library" setting not followed when building a DLL with VS 2008?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc

My goal is to create an MFC/C++ DLL that does not have any dependencies other than the basic Win32 DLLs. So I chose `"Use MFC in a Static Library"` setting in the project properties -> `General` -> `Use of MFC`:

[image]

but when I build this DLL and check the result with the `Dependency Walker` I get this:

[image]

Showing dependencies on the following MFC Dlls:

```
MFC90U.DLL
MSVCR90.DLL
MSVCP90.DLL
```

So what am I doing wrong here?

PS. I'm using Visual Studio 2008

Comment: Is incremental link enabled? Does rebuild all help?

Comment: `MSVCR90.DLL` and `MSVCP90.DLL` aren't MFC binaries.

Comment: @IInspectable: Well, to be honest, I've never thought about it. But, those files are included if you build the project to use "MFC as shared DLLs." They are also not included in Windows XP installation (maybe even Vista) by default, thus have to be distributed via MSI (and a "DLL-Hell".)

Comment: Correct, the runtime support libraries are part of the compiler in VS 2008, not the OS. This has only changed with Windows 10, where the [Universal CRT](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/) is part of the OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got it. What messed me up was the project setting in `C++` -> `Code Generation` -> `Runtime Library`. It was changed to `Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)` and then the following was added to the `stdafx.h` file:

```
#define _AFXDLL
```

So to make it statically link to MFC libraries, I had to change the first setting to `Multi-threaded (/MT)` and comment out the second one.

Comment: Let's hope you understand how [Potential Errors Passing CRT Objects Across DLL Boundaries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235460.aspx) applies to your situation now. By statically linking against the CRT you can no longer safely pass CRT objects (e.g. memory) across DLL boundaries.

Comment: @IInspectable: Let's hope.

Comment: I'd stay off CRT objects for passing across DLL boundaries. I do so using primitive types, memory buffer pointers, or `Heap` allocated memory. Overall, most of my code uses Win32 APIs. CRT stuff comes only as a last resort inside a module. And to your other point, linking to MFC dlls is the worst thing one can do. Been there, done that. No more! You're literally relying on "whatever-state" DLL a user has in their System32 folder. Dll-hell at the finest!

Comment: Uhm... no. **You** deploy **your** dependencies. Into your application's installation directory. There is no DLL hell, if you do things the right way. This is documented under [Deploying Native Desktop Applications (Visual C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zebw5zk9.aspx). As with the CRT, dynamically linking against the MFC library leaves you with options, that would otherwise be impossible.

Comment: Note that using the dynamically linked CRT doesn't fully solve the problem of passing CRT objects between DLL boundaries either - it only works if all modules in the application use the same CRT DLL.  If the executable and all the DLLs are all written by the same vendor that's not usually too much of a problem, but you still need to be aware of it.  (And even more so for DLLs distributed for third-party use.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: It's not sufficient to dynamically link against the CRT, as explained in my first [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41759903/41770646#comment70732856_41770646). But if you do decide to link statically, you have precluded the option to move ownership of CRT objects across DLL boundaries altogether. And recommending to link statically based on the inability to properly deploy an application is fairly poor advice.